# How to disable or ignore Dependabot pull requests?

Tags: github, azure-devops, dependabot

We want to use Dependabot to be informed about updated dependencies, but we do not want Dependabot to create pull requests on its own and do not want automated builds (we use GitHub for Code, Azure DevOps for builds).

There is no clear hint in the docs (https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/automating-dependabot-with-github-actions) to do this.
We already tried to exclude dependabot branches, but that does not work in any form.

```yaml
# Azure DevOps Excludes
pr:
  autoCancel: "true"
  branches:
    exclude:
    - dependabot/*
    - dependabot/**/*
```

We also found the hint on Stack Overflow to set the limit to 0, but still PRs are created

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - directory: "/"
    open-pull-requests-limit: 0
```

Any possibility to use Dependabot just as information source?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Security -> Dependabot -> Configure -> Manage Repository Vulnerability Settings. (This should take you to a URL like https://github.com/yourusername/yourreponame/settings/security_analysis.)
2. Leave the "Dependabot alerts" setting enabled but ensure the "Dependabot version updates" setting is *disabled*.

   If you've previously enabled "Dependabot version updates", you'll have a [`.github/dependabot.yml`](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file) file in your repo, whose purpose is to configure Dependabot's automatic updates. To disable them, delete `dependabot.yml`.

In pictures:

[image: Screenshot showing step 1 above]

[image: Screenshot showing step 2 above]

You will now still be able to view security alerts about your dependencies on GitHub, but Dependabot will not open PRs for them.

Answer (score -1):

By default, `Dependabot` will automatically reset pull requests to resolve any conflicts. If you prefer to handle merge conflicts manually, you can disable this feature with the `rebase-strategy` option.

For rebase strategies, using `disabled` to disable automatic rebasing.

Setting this option will also affect pull requests for security updates to this package manager's manifest file, unless you use `target-branch` to check for version updates on non-default branches.

For `rebase-strategy` example,

```
version: 2

updates:

  - directory: "/"

    schedule:

      interval: "daily"

    # Disable Dependabot pull requests

    rebase-strategy: "disabled"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have tested this for a week now. But dependabot still creates pull requests and triggers automated builds, also with "disabled rebase strategy". Thats my yaml: https://gist.github.com/BenjaminAbt/c2d691d2cb7dd014b671e33598506dfb